# How to put a TreeViewItem into a generated TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, treeviewitem

C#:

```
TreeViewItem treeItem = null;
        treeItem = new TreeViewItem();
        treeItem.Header = "Audit";


        foreach (cAuditTransactionTypeEntity tt in _Pot)
        {
            char[] charsToTrim = {' ', '\t' };
            treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = tt.TransactionType, Name = tt.TransactionType.Replace(" ", "")});
        }

        ToDoList.Items.Add(treeItem);
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="430" Margin="381,409,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="616">
        <TreeViewItem Name="ToDoList" Header="To Do List" FontSize="20" IsExpanded="True">  
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

I have added `TreeViewItems` to a `TreeView`, as shown above. Now I need to add more items under each of these generated `TreeViewItems`. However, as shown in the XAML (also above), the new generated items have not been added, therefore I couldn't name them to reference them in code.

```
treeItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = tt.TransactionType, Name = tt.TransactionType.Replace(" ", "")});
```

Therefore, I added a name generation in this part of my code. Furthermore, this attempt failed and can still not reference the `TreeViewItems` I generated, as the names are only generated at runtime.

Is there another way around this, or is there another way to find each of these generated `TreeViewItems` in code to then add new `Items` underneath them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to keep a reference to the `TreeViewItem` that has just created and Add the Items to that treeViewItem

```
TreeViewItem treeItem = null;
treeItem = new TreeViewItem();
treeItem.Header = "Audit";


foreach (cAuditTransactionTypeEntity tt in _Pot)
{
    TreeViewItem createdTV ;

    char[] charsToTrim = {' ', '\t' };

    //Keep a reference to the created TreeViewItem
    createdTV = new TreeViewItem() { Header = tt.TransactionType, Name = tt.TransactionType.Replace(" ", "")}

    //Create the childs of the createdTreeView

    foreach (cAuditTransactionTypeEntity otherInfo in _OtherList)
    {
        createdTV.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = otherInfo.TransactionType, Name = otherInfo.TransactionType.Replace(" ", "")}) ;
    }

    treeItem.Items.Add(createdTV);
}

ToDoList.Items.Add(treeItem);
```

If what you need to do is a look for a specific child and add items to it...

```
foreach (TreeviewItem objTreeviewItem in ToDoList.Items) 
{
    //change to the desired transaction type
    if ((objTreeviewItem.Header == "TransType")) in your comments
    {
        //add the IDs that correspond to the transaction type
        objTreeviewItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = child.ID, Name = child.Name}) ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, instead of adding all the new items **repeatedly** under every generated item from earlier. I need to specify which item the new items need to go under. For example, certain IDs must go under certain transactiontypes.

Comment: I know how to specify which item the new item needs to go under, I just need to know how to get one of the individual items that were generated.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) and a hierarchical data template instead of doing this in code. If you don't use MVVM, you will fight WPF all the way.

There are good tutorials all over the net, one can be found [here](http://wpftution.blogspot.de/2012/06/hierarchical-databinding-in-treeview.html).

Comment: suggesting MVVM to someone that is having the mentioned problem seems like a using bazuka to kill a mosquito

Comment: If he is to drop WPF the second he solved this problem, then yes. If he wants to use WPF productively, then not.